# How to find all the first values from hashMap

Tags: java

I have a list with `HashMap<Integer, Point3d>` format like in the following way.

```
 {
   {key1,(x1,y1,z1)},
   {key2,(x2,y2,z2)},
   {key3,(x1,y3,z3)},
   {key4,(x1,y4,z4)},
   {key5,(x5,y5,z5)},
   ..
 }
```

First I want to seperate first elements from all the points like `{x1,x2,x1,x1,x5}` and then  remove duplicates like `{x1,x2,x5}` finally length of the result means `{x1,x2,x5}.size()`

In the same way I want to implement for 2nd and 3rd elements of the `Points`.

I tried allot but I didn't find anyway.because we can't able to retrieve values from `HashMap` based on `index`. we can able to retrieve values based on `Key value` But I don't know the `Keyvalues` hashMap.

I tried in the following way.

```
  public int xSideLength(HashMap<Integer, Point3d> coOrdinates) {
    int length=0;
    Set<Integer> keyValues=coOrdinates.keySet();
    Integer[] array=(Integer[]) keyValues.toArray();
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        //logical code
    }
    return length;
}
```

Can anyone suggest me.

Comment: Are you interested in the size of the three sets or the sets themselves?

Comment: Assuming you are working on something 'for fun' and actually want to figure out the solution yourself, here is a tip: It seems to me like you haven't thought about iterating over the values of the hash map using a for loop without indices, e.g. `for (Point3d point : coOrdinates.values()) { ... }`. Your solution is just a few lines more code.

Comment: I suggest you implement your own Map class.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of the following:

```
Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(Point3d point : coordinates.values()) {
    values.add(point.x());
}

return values.size();
```

Comment: Good use of Set to automatically de-dupe -- but point has no method x().

Comment: My Point3d class DOES have a method x()! ;)

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I don't know which Point3d class is used in the question as there is no such class in standard Java I'm aware of. So I just assumed that it has a x() or getX() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps,

1. Put the values of the `HashMap` into a Set with your custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).
2. Implement your [compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) method.
3. Return the set size.

The snippet looks like below,

```
public int xSideLength(HashMap<Integer, Point3d> coOrdinates) {
    int length=0;
    Set<Point3d> values = new TreeSet<Point>(new Comparator<Point3d>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Point3d e1, Point3d e2) {
            return e1.getX().compareTo(e2.getX());
        }
    });
    values.addAll(coOrdinates.values());
    return values.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get elements from the map using the key like this:

```
Set<Integer> keyValues = coOrdinates.keySet();
for (Integer key : keyValues) {
    Point3d point = coOrdinates.get(key);   
    // Your logical code goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void zz() {
    Map<String,Point3d> m = new HashMap<String,Point3d>();

    m.put("k1", new Point3d(1.0, 1.0, 4.0));
    m.put("k2", new Point3d(2.0, 2.0, 2.0));
    m.put("k3", new Point3d(1.0, 3.0, 2.0));
    m.put("k4", new Point3d(1.0, 3.0, 4.0));
    m.put("k5", new Point3d(5.0, 3.0, 2.0));

    Set xvals = new HashSet();
    Set yvals = new HashSet();
    Set zvals = new HashSet();

    double[] coords = new double[3];
    for (Point3d p : m.values()) {
        p.get(coords);
        xvals.add(coords[0]);
        yvals.add(coords[1]);
        zvals.add(coords[2]);
    }

    System.out.println("# unique x: " + xvals.size() + ": " + xvals);
    System.out.println("# unique y: " + yvals.size() + ": " + yvals);
    System.out.println("# unique z: " + zvals.size() + ": " + zvals);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Point3d> entry : coOrdinates.entrySet()) {
    Point3d point = entry.getValue());
}
```